# Is there a way I can replace using <StackLayout> with <Grid> when I want a GestureRecognizer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code.  I would like to replace it with `<Grid>` and simplify it.  Is there a way that I can do this and also implement the `GestureRecognizer`?

```
<ViewCell x:Name="cfs">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20,0,20,0">
       <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OpenPickerCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference cfsPicker}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
       </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
       <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
          <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
             <local:LabelBodyRendererClass Text="Card Front Side" YAlign="Center" XAlign="Center" />
          </StackLayout>
          <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Picker x:Name="cfsPicker" IsVisible="false" SelectedIndexChanged="cfsOnPickerSelectedIndexChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"></Picker>
             <local:LabelBodyRendererClass x:Name="cfsLabel" />
             <Label Text="{x:Static local:FontAwesome.FAAngleRight}" FontFamily="FontAwesome" TextColor="Gray" XAlign="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
          </StackLayout>
       </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `Grid.GestureRecognizers`....

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OpenPickerCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference cfsPicker}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
</Grid>
```